# Unlink token from app facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => $this->app_id,
        'app_secret' => $this->app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
    ]);
    $id = $fb->get("/me",$fbtoken)->getDecodedBody()["id"];

    print_r($fbtoken);
        $response = $fb->post(
        '/'.$id.'/permissions', array("delete"),
        $fbtoken
    );
    print_r($response);
```

I am trying to post `\DELETE /{user-id}/permissions?access_token={APP-ACCESS-TOKEN}` but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = $fb->delete('/me/permissions',array(),$fbtoken);
```

worked. I was trying to post http delete request, while it already had `delete()` method